# Pygame error int obj not callable

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am writing a script in python/pygame, and I run the program (below) but I get an error saying:

if event.type == pygame.QUIT():

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Here is the script

```
def disp_startmenu():
    logo_label = 'WIZARD DEFENSE'
    opt1_label = '(1) START GAME'
    opt2_label = '(2) OPTIONS'
    opt3_label = '(3) QUIT'
    screen.fill(dark_blue)

    render_logo = font3.render(logo_label, 1, green)
    logo_size = render_logo.get_size()
    render_opt1 = font.render(opt1_label, 1, color1)
    opt_size = render_opt1.get_size()
    render_opt2 = font.render(opt2_label, 1, color2)
    render_opt3 = font.render(opt3_label, 1, color3)
    running = True
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                quit()
```

(I did all the imports and pygame.init() before)

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. You can't call `pygame.QUIT`. It's an integer, not a function. Why are you calling it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't include the stacktrace, I am unsure if you have more than one issue. However, this is wrong:

`if event.type == pygame.QUIT():`

It should be,

`if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`

As QUIT is an integer, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this.

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT()
```

To:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT
```

Because pygame.QUIT is not a function it is int (value of 256)